# how to use videoflash.js in react?

Tags: reactjs, video.js

There is 3 kinds of methods to use videoflash.js in video.js as a plugin which contains script tag, Browserify and RequireJS/AMD.  Here is a link。My question is how to use it in react while react use plugins by means of import。
[enter link description here](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-flash)